# An Asian (possibly Chinese) movie/series in which the reincarnation of the antagonist's lover turns out to be one of the main protagonists

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

This was an Asian movie/serie my parents watched a few years ago (before 2018, although I'm not entirely sure when exactly). Most likely Chinese, but it could also be Vietnamese; unlikely to be Korean nor Japanese, although I wouldn't rule them out entirely either. The movie was in full colour and the details didn't look bad, so I would guess it came after 2000.

Although I'm calling it a "movie", I think it would be more correct to call it a "drama", since it had several episodes, much like Korean drama. Most likely the kind of thing you could watch by switching on a specific channel at a certain period of time during the day.

The main plot was happening in modern era, albeit not in 2020, because there are technology we have now which weren't so common back then (I'm thinking about stuffs like modern tablet computer, publicly available drones, smartphones; they most likely already had mobile phones).

Unless specified otherwise, all the characters had dark hair (either brown or black), as far as I remember.

The way I remember it, the protagonists were composed of:

- A woman who is the owner of a restaurant. Since her husband disappeared a long time ago, she had to take care of her child (a boy) alone. She's the main protagonist.
- The husband who actually isn't human but a deity (not specifically a god from what little I know in Asian mythology, but he had special powers and came down to Earth most likely because he fell in love with the former woman), although his physical appearance was human.
- A young man who is friend with the woman. I'm not entirely sure how young he was, because I'm tempted to say he looked like a teenager, but he wasn't THAT young either.
- A young lady who has shared feelings with the young man. I can't remember whether or not they had a healthy relationship or if it was a "I love hating you" kind.
- An Asian man with short blond raised hair who doesn't get important until later on.
- Possibly a 4th man (although I'm not entirely sure) who's also friend with all the others. He's older than the young man.

Some specific moments of the story I remember:

- One day, the child of the main protagonist got badly sick and was bedridden at a hospital. The father decided he couldn't just watch passively, so he came down on Earth looking like a commoner to heal his child. However, healing his child took him quite some focus and energy, so he couldn't return back yet, and part of his legs was invisible. He tried running out of the hospital with a blanket to hide his legs. As he was about to be noticed by his wife coming back, he tried turning around. That's when a nurse took away his blanket and his wife noticed him. Luckily for him, his legs were no longer invisible.
- The couple sat down to have a discussion; most importantly, why he's disappeared for so long. The husband tried to tell her some weak lies, but she replied something in the line of: "We may not have spent a lot of time together, but I know that you're lying when you're scratching the back of your neck. Tell me the truth". That's when he explained that he cannot tell her exactly why, but he had to be away.
- The husband spent some time helping his wife and the restaurant, as well as spending time with his child. He's quite a good cook and the restaurant is getting successful. Eventually though, some other deities came down to pull him back up, because he's not supposed to be there.
- The blond haired guy is just a random guy who got in trouble with the main protagonist. They hate each other for good reasons, although I can't remember why. I think the husband possessed that guy to cheat being pulled back up and to keep helping his wife. That lasted only some time, until the deities came back to pull his spirit back up too. During that time, at some point, the wife yelled at the blond guy for getting too close to the other woman, thinking he might be a weirdo trying to take advantage (actually, it was the husband being helpful towards a friend). To reassure her, he came up with the lie that he's not into women.
- When the husband was pulled out and the guy was back to himself, his only explanation as to what happened during all this time is that he probably got crazy or something, because he doesn't remember anything and he's not into men. Still, because of something he did, they force him to cook to repay his debt. Unfortunately, although we learn later on that he used to like cooking, he explains that he cannot cook properly, because an incident happened and now he cannot taste nor smell anything anymore.
- During the time the husband was still cooking in the kitchen, he prepared some very good food that attracted many people. One of them was likely the henchman of the antagonist, which is also a woman. When she tasted that food, she instantly recognised the cooking of the person she hated and wanted to take revenge. Unfortunately for her, when she came to the restaurant herself, the food was no longer as good, because it was the wife trying to mimic her husband's cooking after he was pulled back. Still, the antagonist wanted to take revenge against the wife.
- The antagonist and her lover also used to be deities living "in the sky". But after they did something forbidden, they were tried and punished into reincarnating into simple human-beings. The punishment involved drinking a liquid that would erase their memory before they are reincarnated. Although her lover did it, she cheated, and so she came to Earth with her power and her memory still intact. She was seeking to find her lover back.
- The husband of the protagonist was among the people who were there during the trial of the antagonist. I think he tried to help the antagonist by speaking in her favour or something. But from her perspective, he was responsible for what happened, so she was seeking revenge.
- At some point before the main story, the antagonist found a man who physically looked like her lover, and she tried to convince him that in his former life, they were a couple. But she freaked him so much that when he tried to run away, he fell off a window and died.
- I'm not entirely sure about this one, but the 4th man was possibly possessed into helping the antagonist at some point, because she made him eat something that allowed her to have total control over him. Eventually, I think he broke the control by accidentally kissing the protagonist (I think he loves her, even if she doesn't; unless it was another woman I don't remember). He still pretended to be under her command for some time, for the sake of helping his friends.
- There was an arc during which the mother and the blond guy participated in a cooking contest. Each team worked as a duo. At this point, the protagonist and the blond guy worked out their disagreement, because they were effectively working together to prepare the best meal together. The antagonist was one of the other contestants, and she was most likely participating with the 4th guy who was possessed.
- At some point in the story, the antagonist accidentally hears the young man asking a florist about some kind of special flower, which the florist doesn't seem to know anything about. That's when the antagonist approached him. Initially, I think he freaked out a bit. But then she decided to show him visions of the memories she had with her lover, and that special flower they kept together; I can't tell for sure what the flower looked like, but it was kept in a special container (I dare say: like the rose from Beauty and the Beast, but not exactly the same kind of container). That's when the young man learned he actually is the reincarnation of the antagonist's lover.
- When the young man came back to the protagonists to tell them, initially, they thought he also got possessed the same way as the 4th man did. The young lady tried to kiss him to free him. Alas, it didn't work because he's not possessed, and he actually is telling them from his own will that he's her lover.

That's about as much as I remember from that movie.